# How can I use vbr.py tool to backup HP Vertica?

Tags: vertica

I try a few things which I saw on internet, I make many examples.
But always I get this error :

### Error:Can not write config file fullback.ini

the screenshot is below
[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change to a directory you have write access to.  It looks like you are in `/home/root`.  Try changing directory to `/home/dbadmin` first.